# Is there a way to get "white cells"/"black cells" views on a square board in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to build the two `black` and `white` views on some square array `board` in Numpy?

Of course `board` could also be itself a view on another array?

We obviously assume the *rank* of the board is even (like the classical 8x8 chess board), since achieving the required task on an odd board is truly easy.

I think it is not fully possible though I have a close match with the following idea:

```
a = np.zeros((81,))
board = a.reshape((9,9))[:8,:8]
black = a[::2]
white = a[1::2]
black += 1
white += 2
print(board)
```

Which almost does what is required: `board` is some 8x8 view on an internal array, and you can intialize black and white cells separately by using two other views. But this solution is not perfect since the two `black` and `white` views also contain useless hidden cells.

Is there a better solution for this question?

*This is a mere theoretical challenge between colleagues (and not a "what are you trying to achieve?" question from some production context).*

Comment: What do you mean by the "rank" of the board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `black` and `white` needn't be 1D it can be done:

```
board = np.zeros((18,12))[::3,::2]
# non contiguous to make it a bit intersting

m,n = board.shape
v4d = board.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2)
black = np.einsum("ijkj->ijk",v4d)
white = np.einsum("ijkj->ijk",v4d[...,::-1])

board
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
black += 1
board
# array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
#        [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
#        [1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
#        [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.]])
white += 2
board
# array([[1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
#        [2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
#        [2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.],
#        [2., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1.]])
```

Comment: This is very nice. Actually black and white didn't need to be 1D array in my question; thus your answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think your hunch that it is impossible is correct.

If your `board` is not itself a view, it is easy to get views that you can operate on:

```py
>>> board = np.zeros((8, 8), int)
>>> black = board.ravel()[::2]
>>> black.base is board # is black a view of board?
True
```

If `board` is a view of `a`, the memory won't be aligned in a way that you can get the views you want, so `ravel` will instead create copies:

```py
>>> a = np.zeros(81)
>>> board = a.reshape(9, 9)[:8, :8]
>>> board.base is a # is board a view of a?
True
>>> black = board.ravel()[::2]
>>> black.base in (a, board) # is black a view of a or board?
False
```

One workaround I can think of is to split each view into two:

```
>>> black0 = board[::2, ::2]
>>> black1 = board[1::2, 1::2]
>>> black0.base is a and black1.base is a # are both views of a?
True
```